# Load and display output cells in existing Jupyter notebook in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have an existing `.ipynb` notebook file that contains `"outputs"` entries for most of the cells. When I load this in VSCode (1.39.2, Python Extension 2019.10.44104), it does not load/show the `"outputs"` content.

In my case, the content of the `.ipynb` is not reproducible (think platform-dependent timing data) so simply re-running the cells when I load in VSCode is not an option -  I need to be able to view the existing `"outputs"` content alongside all the other cell data without re-running the cells.

How can I show the existing `"outputs"` content when loading an existing `.ipynb` file in VSCode?

**UPDATE**

Example `.ipynb` file: https://github.com/SethMMorton/fastnumbers/blob/2.2.1/TIMING_36.ipynb

Also, a detail that I didn't initially think was important but probably is: all of the output cells in this notebook are code-generated markdown.

Comment: If this is not possible, let me know and I will just file a feature request. Though, I would be surprised if I am the first person who wants to load a previously-created notebook and not have to regenerate all the output data instead of just loading it...

Comment: Hey @SethMMorton. I'm a developer on this extension. Is this .ipynb (or a small repro file) something that you can share? Previous outputs should always be shown when opening up a .ipynb file. Sounds like we might have a bug here. If you have a repro that you can share you can send it to me at ianhu [at] microsoft.com and I can take a look quick.

Comment: @IanHuff I will update the question text with this information, and some extra details that may help (now that I know this is *supposed* to work).

Comment: @IanHuff Also, if you want me to file this issue in GitHub I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at this and while I do repro it with our currently released bits I do not see the issue in our development branch. You could try installing our development build from here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build

Or just picking up the fix with our next main release, which is this week I believe. Does the new bits example look right here?

Old bits:
[image]

Current bits (should be releasing soon):
[image]

Comment: Yup, that looks like the expected output!  I’ll report back when the new version is released.